# Convert api data to HTML in python

Tags: html, json, django, mongodb, api

The want the data I got in json format to be able to view and code in HTML. This is the python code I have written. The data is received from MongoDB

```
def get_audit_run(request, theA=0, theR=0, result=''):

  if 'url' in request.GET:
    page = request.GET['url']
  else:
    page = ''

  theinput_dict = observepoint.get_audit_run(theA, theR, result, page)

  # Transform python object back into json
  theoutput_json = json.dumps(theinput_dict,  indent=4)  


  #return render(request, 'theA.html',  {"data" : output_json} )
  return HttpResponse(theoutput_json, content_type='application/json')
```

My result:

```
{
"a": 72040,
"b": 60,
"c": false,
"d": 100,
"sm": false,
"id": 885057,
"completed": "2018-08-27T15:34:20.000-04:00",
"tU": 99,
"userId": 4267,
"started": "2018-08-27T15:12:46.000-04:00",
"limit": 100,
"SF": [
    "abc",
    "xyz",
    "pqr"
]
}
```

I want to render the results above to HTML table. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render that data as HTML, then you have to render that data. Returning the HttpResponse will simply return the Json data. You should use render or render_to_response.

```
  return render(request, 'theA.html',  {"data" : output_json} )
```

This line will render the Json data in "theA.html" template. Just access the json data as

```
{{ data.id }}
{{ data.completed }}
```

Comment: I am getting a blank page when I try this

Comment: Post your html.

Comment: is the syntax provided is for Jinja alone?